# Jenkins - SSL without displaying httpsKeyStorePassword in process string?

Tags: ssl, jenkins, keytool

Is there any way to configure jenkins for SSL without passing the httpsKeyStore and httpsKeyStorePassword arguments to the jenkins.war?

I've tried setting the values as JAVA_ARGS, and JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE/JENKINS_HTTPS_KEYSTORE_PASSWORD environment variables, but neither make their way to the winstone web container.

Any ideas? If I install as a system package vs. launching the .war directly, can you configure this in the init script or a file on the host? My main goal is to hide the keystore password in the process string, but I'm not sure how it's possible when launching Jenkins directly from the .war file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who needs this - https://github.com/jenkinsci/winstone#configuration-file

You can set the keystore path and password in the winstone.properties configuration file.

Comment: FWIW the property name for the keystore password in `winstone.properties` seems to mirror the command line argument (`httpsKeyStorePassword`).